# Jackson: Share state between custom (de) serializer

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jackson

Is there a way to share a state in which a custom (de)serializer can set a value/flag to be used for another custom (de)serializer?

In my use case when deserializing I need a child object to set a flag for the root object.

When serializing I need the root object to set a flag for child objects.

Many thanks.

Comment: *What* are you doing with deserialization?

Comment: which flag want to sett?

Comment: There is an object, which has a list of sub objects. The sub objects have a time field which can be a unix epoch number or a string "hh:mm". Regardless the format used, the sub objects always store a unix representation. However I need to store in the root object which format of type is used. That information is known at sub object level, that's why I need to share custom application flags between deserializers. When my service return the result must return time fields with the same format used in the request, the flag is known at root object and should be passed to sub objects.

Comment: All sub objects must use the same format, so store in the sub object the format used is redundant and must be avoided @Makoto